# Android Webview How download Blob file

Tags: javascript, java, android, ajax

i have this code use in webview

```
public static String getBase64StringFromBlobUrl(String blobUrl) {
    if(blobUrl.startsWith("blob")){
        return "javascript: var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();" +
            "xhr.open('GET', '"+ blobUrl +"', true);" +
            "xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/pdf');" +
            "xhr.responseType = 'blob';" +
            "xhr.onload = function(e) {" +
            "    if (this.status == 200) {" +
            "        var blobPdf = this.response;" +
            "        var reader = new FileReader();" +
            "        reader.readAsDataURL(blobPdf);" +
            "        reader.onloadend = function() {" +
            "            base64data = reader.result;" +
            "            Android.getBase64FromBlobData(base64data);" +
            "        }" +
            "    }" +
            "};" +
            "xhr.send();";
    }
    return "javascript: console.log('It is not a Blob URL');";
}
```

its work only pdf, zip and other files but i need download Psd, Jpg, PNG files. how make it?

thanks all :)